# Java script: how to get Workflow Id from Workflow Task Form

Tags: workflow, javascript, task-list

I need to get the Workflow Id with java script after editing a Workflow Task. What I have this far is only a script that gets the Task Id when the EditForm is opened:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var xId = JSRequest.QueryString["ID"];
//need to get the Workflow Id here
```

Any suggestions? All help would be appreciated!

Edit: tried to look for the Workflow Id with REST and Postman on the Workflow Task List but also there I can't find the Workflow Id Does this mean it's impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean Workflow Instance Id, right? 
It depends on SharePoint version.

**SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013 (`Platform Type: SharePoint 2010 Workflow`)**

Workflow Instance Id is stored in field `WorkflowInstanceID` (Type: `SP.Guid`)

Example:

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));

getListItem( listId,itemId,
   function(item){
       var workflowInstanceId = item.get_fieldValues()['WorkflowInstanceID'].toString();
       console.log(workflowInstanceId);
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

**SharePoint 2013 (`Platform Type: SharePoint 2013 Workflow`)**

Workflow Instance Id is stored in field `WF4InstanceId`

Example

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));

getListItem( listId,itemId,
   function(item){
       var workflowInstanceId = item.get_fieldValues()['WF4InstanceId'];
       console.log(workflowInstanceId);
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

---

**getListItem function**

```
function getListItem(listId,itemId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   ctx.load(item);

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(item); 
      },
      error);
}
```

Comment: exactly, meant the Workflow Instance Id :). And your code worked perfectly, thanks!!!!!!