# How to Workflow ID of a SharePoint List Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I need to know the WF ID associated with a List, I have gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220612/get-workflow-id-for-list-workflow) link but it didn't help me out. Please suggest

Comment: What are you going to use it for? Is it a one-off or do you need to retrieve it using code?

Comment: Anyhow, if any OOTB option is available that will be well and good for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to List settings > Workflow Settings > you can open the workflow and see the SubscriptionID as part of the url (with {} encoded as %7B  and %7D at each end)

Comment: Are you sure Subscription ID and Workflow ID both are the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the details easily by using the [PnP PowerShell Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "List Name" -Includes WorkflowAssociations
Write-Host $list.WorkflowAssociations.Id
```

Comment: Not worked, showing blank log

Comment: Did you get anything on $list.WorkflowAssociations at all? (or $list for that matter...)

Comment: i got only List-ID, $list.WorkflowAssociations showing 0 count

Answer (score 0):

How to retrieve workflow id by using jsom in SharePoint online for your reference:

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/how-to-retrieve-workflow-id-by-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-online/